Tanstack query setMutationDefaults Typescript error
Situation
While using setMutationDefaults to manage my useMutations efficiently, tanstack query seems to have trouble on recognizing my mutation function data type.
Code

First i used setMuationDefaults to set  deletePlaceScrap async function

queryClient.setMutationDefaults(['deletePlaceScrap'], { mutationFn: deletePlaceScrap})


This is my deletePlaceScrap function


Please look only at the parameters (code works fine)

interface PlaceDeleteScrapType {
  placeId: number
  accessToken: string
}
export const deletePlaceScrap = async ({ placeId, accessToken }: PlaceDeleteScrapType) => {
  const Route = BACKEND_ROUTES.PLACE.SCRAP.DELETE

  const res = await fetch(`/server/${Route.url}`, {
    method: Route.method,
    headers: {
      Authorization: accessToken,
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      placeId: placeId,
    }),
    credentials: 'include',
  })
  if (!res.ok) {
    const error = new Error('An error occurred while fetching places')
    toast({ title: 'Failure occured' })

    error.message = await res.json()
    throw error
  }

  return
}


On my Component that uses it, it gets typescript error
const { mutate } = useMutation({ mutationKey: ['deletePlaceScrap'] })
mutate(placeId: id, accessToken: user.accessToken })

Argument of type '{ placeId: number; accessToken: any; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'void'
What's the problem????!!!
